# How to block user access to ports that another user opened?

Tags: firewall

I operate a Linux server where local users can run individual "Jupyter analytics notebooks", which start a web interface on a new port. But currently a local user can just change the port in the browser URL bar and thereby access other local user's interfaces.

Can I restrict access to ports that a user opened to only this user (on the local machine)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use an [authenticator](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authenticators.html) or something else within the application itself?

Failing that Then it's really likely to be quite a palaver. If your users have workstations with fixed IP addressed then you could allow access to a particular port only from a particular IP address.

Comment: It would be an option (later), but it requires yet another management of a credentials scheme. I was hoping there is an independent firewall solution. I cannot do it IP based, since most people come from the same IP (in fact local at the moment).

Comment: Either do it right or don't bother.

Comment: @istheEnglishway What's the right way?